# BackgroundTransferRequest DownloadLocation to get the Response content

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-transfer

I am uploading a file to the server using BackgroundTransferRequest object. I need to access the response header sent from the server. Based on the research, I understand that there is no direct access to the Response of the request and one possible work around is to provide a download location to which the response content will be written. 
However, when I try to do that, there is no data written to that file and its 0 bytes. My request server is actually sending a response having ONLY the headers (without any content).

So my question is, does the response have to have body in order to get the response written to the DownloadLocation?

My code sample:

```
var request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(targetUri)
{
    DownloadLocation = new Uri(downloadTo, UriKind.Relative),
    UploadLocation = new Uri(uploadFrom, UriKind.Relative),
    Method = "POST"
};
```

Comment: Anyone with any workaround to this issue?

Comment: one suggestion: check if your `downloadLocation` is in windows phone isolatedStorage's "shared\transfers" location or not. this could be reason for the data not written.